# How to redirect http to https in tomcat and apache integration.

Tags: apache, https, tomcat8

When I am going to hit URL without the help of https in an integration of apache and tomcat8 then URL doesn't work. But when I am using https with URL then it's working fine.

Please help me to redirect HTTP to HTTPS.

Answer (score 0):

vi /etc/httpd/conf/httpd.conf

(By default value in httpd.conf file)

Add below value between `<VirtualHost *.80>`

`RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]`

`<VirtualHost *:80>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{HTTPS}  !=on
RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
 </VirtualHost>`